# Inconsistent XML File Structure

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading data in from 3rd party xml files (so I do not have control over structure and content of those files).

In some cases a file does not have consistent elements/attributes, so when I try to ready through the file the program crashes.

Is there anyway to check if the attribute exists on each pass through and skip that attribute or default the value to null, without skipping the entire record i.e. I still want the rest of the fields.

The attributes commented out are the ones currently that do not always appear in each record i.e. AbbreviationChar will appear in the first 30 records in the xml file but 31st record will not list this as an attribute, then on record 32 it is showing again.

```
public IEnumerable<KronosPayCode> ImportPayCodes()
        {
            var processingOrder = _db.KronosConfigurationFiles.ToList();

            if (!processingOrder.Any()) return null;
            var xmlFile = Path.Combine(_xmlPath, "WSAPayCode.xml");
            var stream = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            var payCodeCollection = xdoc.Descendants("WSAPayCode");
            var kronosCollection = new List<KronosPayCode>();
            foreach (var element in payCodeCollection)
            {
                var abbreviationChar = element.Attribute("AbbreviationChar");
                var payCode = new KronosPayCode
                {
                    Name = element.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    AutoResolved = element.Attribute("AutoResolved").Value.IsBool(),
                    EditExcuseAbsn = element.Attribute("EditExcuseAbsn").Value.IsBool(),
                    PersistPceSw = element.Attribute("PersistPceSw").Value.IsBool(),
                    //AbbreviationChar=element.Attribute("AbbreviationChar").Value,
                    EditCntToCdotSw=element.Attribute("EditCntToCdotSw").Value.IsBool(),
                    EditAffShfTotal=element.Attribute("EditAffShfTotal").Value.IsBool(),
                    EditCntToOt=element.Attribute("EditCntToOt").Value.IsBool(),
                    PayUsingWeightedAverageRate=element.Attribute("PayUsingWeightedAverageRate").Value.IsBool(),
                    RequiresMgrApproval=element.Attribute("RequiresMgrApproval").Value.IsBool(),
                    WeightedAverageRateIsComputedDaily=element.Attribute("WeightedAverageRateIsComputedDaily").Value.IsBool(),
                    JustAutoResExpAsWorked=element.Attribute("JustAutoResExpAsWorked").Value.IsBool(),
                    AssociatedDurationPayCodeName=element.Attribute("AssociatedDurationPayCodeName").Value,
                    WeightedAverageRateContributionsUseAnAdjustedRate=element.Attribute("WeightedAverageRateContributionsUseAnAdjustedRate").Value.IsBool(),
                    ScheduleHoursType=element.Attribute("ScheduleHoursType").Value,
                    CheckAvlbltySw=element.Attribute("CheckAvlbltySw").Value.IsBool(),
                    //WageAddition=element.Attribute("WageAddition").Value,
                    VisibleInMainArea=element.Attribute("VisibleInMainArea").Value.IsBool(),
                    IsMoneyCategory=element.Attribute("IsMoneyCategory").Value.IsBool(),
                    AmountType=element.Attribute("AmountType").Value,
                    VisibleInReport=element.Attribute("VisibleInReport").Value.IsBool(),
                    ContributesToWeightedAverageRates=element.Attribute("ContributesToWeightedAverageRates").Value.IsBool(),
                    //UnjustAutoResExpAsWorked=element.Attribute("UnjustAutoResExpAsWorked").Value.IsBool(),
                    //WageMultiply=element.Attribute("WageMultiply").Value,
                    //Type=element.Attribute("Type").Value,
                    //VisibleToUser=element.Attribute("VisibleToUser").Value.IsBool(),
                    CustomerId = 11,
                };

                _db.KronosPayCodes.Add(payCode);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                kronosCollection.Add(payCode);
                }

                return kronosCollection;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `XAttribute` to string instead of accessing it's `Value` property to avoid null reference exception :

```
........
AbbreviationChar = (string)element.Attribute("AbbreviationChar"),
........
```

With that you'll *safely* get `null` value if attribute `AbbreviationChar` is not found.